# Copy to clipboard in JS

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard

I am using **document.execCommand("copy")** function to copy a piece of text from code in JavaScript. It works fine for Firefox,Chrome and IE. However it is not working in Safari. I have researched a lot to fix this but did not got anything.

Comment: Yes I know it is not supported in safari. So how can I execute copy to clipboard functionality in safari ?

Comment: @Kritika Unfortunately you cannot, there is no browser support. The only other way is flash based, which is also not going to work either because browser blocking the flash from running. And support for [clipboard api](http://caniuse.com/#search=clipboard) isn't good either.

Comment: Is there any plug in available to implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

I've searched for some solutions and I've found one that actually works: http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/copy2clipboard.htm

Basically, example could be something like:

```
var $input = $(' some input/textarea ');
$input.val(result);
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|ipod|iphone/i)) {
  var el = $input.get(0);
  var editable = el.contentEditable;
  var readOnly = el.readOnly;
  el.contentEditable = true;
  el.readOnly = false;
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(el);
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  el.setSelectionRange(0, 999999);
  el.contentEditable = editable;
  el.readOnly = readOnly;
} else {
  $input.select();
}
document.execCommand('copy');
$input.blur();
```

Comment: I tried the above stated solution and it is not working on safari.